# AWS Cognito OIDC provider PKCE

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, pkce

I have an Amplify application which uses Cognito for authentication. I need to allow users to sign in through a third party. I have set them up as an OIDC identity provider in Cognito. However this third party only supports the code grant flow with PKCE, and the request that Cognito makes to the OIDC provider isn't made with PKCE (no code_challenge parameter is sent).

Looking at the settings for OIDC providers and Cognito app client, I'm unable to find a way to enable this. Is it possible to have Cognito make this request with PKCE?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't unfortunately:

- Cognito supports PKCE for direct requests from clients
- But I don't think it does for federated connections to other identity providers

Logically this should work in one of the following ways:

- Cognito could provide it as a setting you could toggle for an identity provider
- Or Cognito could derive it from the [code_challenge_methids_supported](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8414#section-2) metadata parameter
- The target IDP should probably support classic OIDC messages without PKCE in order to be a compliant OIDC provider - this might be your best bet

I used Okta as an IDP for Cognito a while ago - Okta returns the above metadata field - but Cognito did not use PKCE - see the [Federated OpenID Connect Messages](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) section after Step 5.

Comment: One of the many undocumented Cognito pitfalls.

I was able to confirm that the redirect to the OIDC identity provider does not include a code_challenge. 

The irony is that their documentation showcases a Salesforce example even though Salesforce recommends PKCE for all oauth flows. 